# Add the products in cart, the total amount displayed multiple times in cart page using angular 6

Tags: angular

I am developing an E-commerce Website. In this, if I add the products from the home page, the products are listed in cart page but the amount is not displayed or displayed multiple times depending upon the products.

Here's my code:

cart.ts

```ts
get Total(){
    let total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.cartItem.length; i++) {
        if (this.cartItem[i].Price) {
          total += this.cartItem[i].Price * this.cartItem[i].Quantity;
            this.totalamount = total;
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

cart.html:

```html
  <div class="total-price">

              <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-6 col-lg-8">
                    Price({{cartItem.length}} items)
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                    <i class="fa fa-inr"></i>&nbsp; {{ Total }}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

I get the output like this:

[image: Output]

I want to display the total amount as only one time for all products. How can this be achieved?

Comment: At the moment it looks like you're display the total with an `ngfor` loop, so it will repeat. Move it outside the loop

Comment: Moved from the ngfor loop now also displayed mulitple times and the value is not displayed.

Comment: If it's displaying multiple times, it must still be inside a loop. Are you able to either create a StackBlitz that reproduces the issue, or provide the JSON you're using for `cartItem`

Comment: Hi there @vino! Please take note that it's a bad idea to handle your code in one getter. Consider using a method instead.

Answer (score 1):

As you have the total inside the `ngFor`, it will be displayed for each item of the list, so you see many totals getting displayed.

I would recommend you to have a typescript method defined in the component.ts and call it in the HTML where you want to display the total.

```
getTotal(){
    let total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.cartItems.length; i++) {
        if (this.cartItems[i].amount) {
            total += this.cartItems[i].amount * this.cartItems[i].quantity;
            this.totalamount = total;
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: can u explain what is the amount you used in the code and totalamount is product of price and quantity where u did the calculation

Comment: replace amount with totalamount

Comment: It displayed 0 in the total amount

Comment: use    <i class="fa fa-inr"></i>&nbsp; {{ getTotal()}}

Comment: It displayed 0 only

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/simple-ngfor-li-element-71nbbj?file=app%2Fapp.component.html